# How to prove by induction that the if the sum of n positive numbers is n than their product is smaller equal to 1?

Tags: inequality, induction

Hi what is a way to prove that if we have n positive numbers which sum is n than their product is smaller equal to 1?

Comment: Use the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: @GReyes How can i do that?

Comment: You got your answer.

Comment: @GReyes How can it be done by induction

Comment: @EntiolLiko You have been given two answers that are essentially saying the same thing. Have you tried looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_by_induction)?

Answer (score 1):

The question is more clearly phrased as follows:

> Given $n$ positive real numbers $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_n$ such that $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=n$, prove that:
>
> $$a_1a_2\cdot \ldots \cdot a_n\leq 1$$

This is pretty much a direct application of the [AM-GM](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/) inequality for $n$ numbers, that is:

$$\frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdot \ldots \cdot a_n}$$

With the given condition, this implies:

$$1 \geq \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdot \ldots \cdot a_n}$$

and now raise to the $n$th power to get the desired conclusion.

Comment: Yes but I need it done by induction